# App console output and correct encoding to TMemo in Delphi

Tags: delphi, encoding, console-application

I get from other statckoverflow post the function listed below.

I have a encoding problem with accented chars to show the result in a TMemo.
for sample if I use:

```
Memo1.Text := GetDosOutput('Help DIR');
```

My Memo1.Text shows:

```
"Exibe uma lista de arquivos e subdiret¢rios em um diret¢rio.
 DIR [unidade:][caminho][arquivo] [/A[[:]atributos]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]ordem_de_classifica‡Æo]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]campo_de_tempo]]
  [/W] [/X] [/4]
  .......
"
```

Please, How do I convert the result string of the function to shows correctly in TMemo?

I tried

```
Memo1.Text := UnicodeString(GetDosOutput('Help DIR'));
```

but, no look.

```
function GetDosOutput(CommandLine: string; Work: string = 'C:\'): string;
var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  WorkDir: string;
  Handle: Boolean;
begin
  Result := '';
  with SA do begin
    nLength := SizeOf(SA);
    bInheritHandle := True;
    lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  end;
  CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
  try
    with SI do
    begin
      FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
      cb := SizeOf(SI);
      dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
      wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
      hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
      hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
    end;
    WorkDir := Work;
    Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine),
                            nil, nil, True, 0, nil,
                            PChar(WorkDir), SI, PI);
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
    if Handle then
      try
        repeat
          WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
          if BytesRead > 0 then
          begin
            Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
            Result :=Result + Buffer;
          end;
        until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
        WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
      finally
        CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
        CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
      end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What's incorrect about it? What result are you expecting?

Comment: Console returns text in the OEM character set encoding. You want to convert it to either a specific ANSI codepage (probably 1252 from what's given: `ó`> `¢`) or Unicode, depending on the version of Delphi you are using.  You could either use `OEMToCharBuff` or convert using `TEncoding`.

Comment: @JerryDodge it's pretty obvious - he's expecting `subdiretórios` and getting `subdiret¢rios`.

Comment: @J... Yes I just saw that, except I don't know such languages to know how it's supposed to look. So to me, it's not quite as obvious.

Comment: @JerryDodge Well... nobody spells with cents ;)

Comment: The problem is with accent char as JerryDodge shows.

Comment: Thanks to all and to J... I solved with the function: function StrOemToAnsi(const aStr : AnsiString) : AnsiString;
var
  Len : Integer;
begin
  Len := Length(aStr);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  OemToCharBuffA(PAnsiChar(aStr), PAnsiChar(Result), Len);
end;

Comment: @LuizAlves  can you post your code as an answer so that this question can be easily reviewed by future delphi users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From J..  suggestion,  I created the  StrOemToAnsi function showing below using
OemToCharBuffA.

To test I did:

```
procedure Tfm_nh_maindicom.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var s:string;
    function StrOemToAnsi(const aStr : AnsiString) : AnsiString;
    var
      Len : Integer;
    begin
      if aStr = '' then Exit;
      Len := Length(aStr);
      SetLength(Result, Len);
      OemToCharBuffA(PAnsiChar(aStr), PAnsiChar(Result), Len);
    end;
begin
  S:=GetDosOutput('Help DIR');
  Memo1.Text:=StrOemToAnsi(s);
end;
```

And the result in Memo1 was:

```
"Exibe uma lista de arquivos e subdiretórios em um diretório.

DIR [unidade:][caminho][arquivo] [/A[[:]atributos]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]ordem_de_classificação]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]campo_de_tempo]]
  [/W] [/X] [/4]
....
"
```